# Searching in more than one table, SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Results I'd like to achieve: One record for each customer. 
Number of tables: 3 (Account Master, MeterStatus, Codes.MeterStatus)

Hello, I'm trying to find one record for each customer in the following tables, Account Master, MeterStatus, Codes.MeterStatus. Account Master contains customers who are active (need to find here if its available), Meterstatus table contains customers who have been enrolled in our system, but might not have made it to active status, and codes.meterstatus is simply used to decipher codes that are located in meterstatus table.

I've already tried the following variations, but they have not provided the results I expected.

```
    Select *
  FROM [xx].[dbo].[AccountMaster] EAM
        full join [xx].[Link].[MeterStatus] MS on ms.UAN = eam.UAN
        left join xx.codes.MeterStatus on ms.MeterStatus = MeterStatus.MeterStatus

        where eam.UAN in ('055013920') or ms.UtilityAccountNumber in ('055013920')
            and ms.MeterStatus not in ('4','5')
```

---

```
  FROM [xx].[Link].[MeterStatus] MS
    left join xx.dbo.AccountMaster EAM on ms.UAN = eam.UAN 
    left join xx.codes.MeterStatus on ms.MeterStatus = MeterStatus.MeterStatus

where  ms.UANin ('055013920')
 and ms.MeterStatus not in ('4','5')
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Sample data... expected output...

Comment: Does the following produce results?
SELECT *
FROM [xx].[Link].[MeterStatus] MS 
WHERE ms.UAN in ('055013920')
    AND ms.MeterStatus not in ('4','5')